# JavaScript not passing arguments το WindowScriptObject?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cocoa, webview, xcode6

First off, let me tell you that I've used webviews in Cocoa like 100 times. However, I have no clue as to what goes wrong...

**Here's the JS part:**

```
window.objc.log_("Selected Element!");
```

**And here's the Objective-C part:**

```
- (void)log:(NSString*)msg
{
    NSLog(@"JS: %@",msg);
}
```

**And here's the output:**

```
JS: (null)
```

What's going on?

---

**P.S.** The WebView's `windowScriptObject` has been correctly set and `isSelectorExcludedFromWebScript:` and `isKeyExcludedFromWebScript:` have been defined. (The function wouldn't be called at all anyway, if they weren't set...)