# Bizarre issue with Coffeescript - Literal argument send as null

Tags: javascript, jquery, objective-c, cocoa, coffeescript

OK here's the outline of my Coffeescript:

```
(($) ->
    class MyClass 

        MyFunction: (someArg)->
             @iframe().find("[id]").click((e)=>
                window.objc.log_("SOMETHING");
             );
) jQuery
```

For those of you wondering, `objc` is the Objective-C object which declares `log_`. The thing is the function IS called. But the string, even when I use a literal one (as in the example) is `null`.

If I call the exact same function from outside the `(($)-> ...) jQuery` block, it works fine.

What's going on?

---

**P.S.** This is the [related question I posted earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26526045/javascript-not-passing-arguments-%CF%84%CE%BF-windowscriptobject), but the more I'm looking at it, the more I tend to believe it's JavaScript-related than Objective-C-related...

Comment: It doesn't look JavaScript related. Your script is fine.

Comment: @Jivings It *must* be. I just tried calling it from within `MyFunction` it still works great. The only place it doesn't is from the `click` anonymous function... :S

Comment: With a String literal that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Jivings True. But I've wasted so many hours on this one, I really don't know what to think of..

Comment: have you tried a different syntax for wrapping the call. I think what you have would be equivocal to a jquery ready function, but you might just try removing the `(($->...)` bit and replace with `jQuery.ready ->` or `$ ->`

Comment: Why are you using an SIF to define the `$` shortcut for `jQuery` when you're not using any jQuery in your class at all? Is that just a leftover of snipping out the irrelevant details or do you really mean to use `$(-> ...)` (i.e. the `jQuery(function() { ... })` shortcut for `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you somehow put a click handler on an element inside an iframe. Then the window object outside is not the same as in your iframe. When click happens then the scope is the iframe.

See fiddle for outer: http://jsfiddle.net/6fzvkcte/1/
It has an iframe with an other fiddle. You can see that values of window.document.body.children.length variables are different.

```
window.document.body.children.length
```

But it is a bit scary to bind a click handler from a parent window to an element in an iframe. This way you can bind to keydown also and steal my passwords and money. As you can see it does not do anything in the fiddle (at least in Chrome).